# SQL Server : disadvantages of IDENTITY constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints, identity

I would like to talk about disadvantages of `IDENTITY` constraint in SQL Server. In my opinion, it is helpful but may cause anomalies with foreign keys.

Example:

```
create table letters
(
    ID int identity,
    letter varchar(1)
)
```

Now I would create two letters:

```
insert into letters (letter) values ('a');
insert into letters (letter) values ('b');
```

and create a table of references to each letter:

```
create table references
(
    ID int identity,
    ID_letter int references letters(ID),
    value int
)
```

I want to have reference to 'b' letter so that I make:

```
insert into references (ID_letter,value) values (2,100)
```

But now if I delete 'a' letter and execute inserting of 'b' in another database, I must change that reference to 1 instead of 2, because ID of 'b' is now 1.

That's why I would rather use name as primary key and reference to name, not ID identity. But it is not so easy with longer varchars, example cities - it is much easier to write ID of a city instead of full names. What is your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, are you trying to have a foreign key reference an entirely different database?

Comment: It is not a problem with `identity` per se, it is an eternal holy war of natural vs surrogate primary keys. Both approaches have strong and weak sides, so everything depends on your particular circumstances.

Comment: @jakub, I think your question is really about surrogate key pros and cons.  This question is too broad.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: You are right that if you need to create key values in two places then IDENTITY probably isn't the right way to do it. Note however that a table can have more than one key. You can make Letter unique (as well as ID) and use the Letter as a more appropriate key for external references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that you're misunderstanding what Identity is. It's a broad topic as well.

Identity is just a (unique) numbering of a specific row. It's not automatically a key, primary or otherwise, unless you make it so.
It's also not database wide and it's definitely not globally unique. And it's not used in that manner unless you're doing something wrong.

Identities are often used as primary key to avoid having to make a composite key of a number of rows because it makes it easier to look up and it reduces size of indexes. 
And even if it is a key, it does not have to be the clustered index of the table, but can just be a non-clustered index. That's down a related although still alternate route, so I'll not go too deep in that direction.

So an identity would never cause anomalies with foreign keys. Your usage of identity might cause problems, but that's down to what you're trying to do, more so than the tool itself.

If you want data keys to be consistent across multiple databases, you'd use a "system key" of sorts. Often founded in the data itself or calculated from the data.
For that you would normally use uniqueidentifiers (guids), sequence numbers generated in applications, or in case of an alphabet, the letter it self is a valid comparison key.

When it comes to cities, you could use the name if you're sure spelling will be handled, otherwise, you'd include another identifier based on what ever logic you have between the two systems you want to talk together and how you exchange data.

Also when talking cross databases, primary keys are not automatically meant to be the same, and references between the two even less so; even if the data is easily related.   Because it depends a lot on how data is used (which again leads us back to the building of indexes).

Identity is simply a tool in the database toolbox. How you use it is up to you, but as any tools it's better suited for some tasks and not suited for every task.